# How to show a rounded number in python when the number is 0?

Tags: python, rounding

This is what I currently have and it does the math correctly but when i use 5 as input the number comes out to be 165.1 but i need it to show 165.10.

```
print("This program converts from feet and inches to centimeters.")
feet = float(input("Enter feet: "))
inches = float(input("Enter inches: "))
n1 = float(feet * 30.48)
n2 = float(inches * 2.54)
n3 = float(n1 + n2)
n4 = round(n3,2)
print("\nThe length is", n4, "cm.")
```

Comment: Do you need a fixed amount of significant digits (i.e. should ``12`` output ``12.000``) or is a fixed amount of digits after the decimal dot sufficient?

Comment: I need it to show 2 spots behind the decimal regardless what the number is.

Comment: I have no idea why the correct answer was deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Python format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) ([docs for 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)):

```
number = 10.1
print("{:.2f}".format(number))
```

---

General remarks about your code: You don’t need the `float()` cast around your arithmetic operations (but you may need it around `input(…)`, as `input(…)` may return a string, depending on your python version). Doing arithmetical operations on numbers again gives numbers (floats, in your case).

Comment: For single substitutions - sometimes `format(number, '.2f')` reads better

Comment: when i use your function i get the following error: ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: @AmandaC. You’re not passing a number then. With your original code, it would work (replacing ``number`` by ``n4``).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [3]: "%.2f" % 160.1
Out[3]: '160.10'
```

Also will work

More http://floating-point-gui.de/languages/python/

Comment: I tried using this and all it does is give me a invalid snytix.

Comment: Can you show us what exactly you trying ?, you must pass a value to format fucntion